# Transformation to canonically conjugate coordinates in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, canonical-conjugation

Just like we can Fourier transform a field from $$x^\mu = (ct, x,y,z) \rightarrow p^\mu = (E/c, p_x, p_y, p_z)$$ via a Fourier transform, for spherical coordinates can we Fourier transform in the same way from $$X^\mu = (ct, r, \theta, \phi) \rightarrow P^\mu = (E/c, P_r, P_\theta, P_\phi)~?$$

This would seem straight forward but my concern is that $p_\theta $ and $ p_\phi $ are angular momenta, and thus transform like the Angular Momentum matrix $$M^{\mu \nu} = (x^\mu p^\nu - x^\nu p^\mu).$$ 
Unlike the energy and radial momentum, which transform as normal vectors. Is this a problem at all for describing dynamics in canonically conjugate spherical coordinates?

Comment: Hint: 4-momentum is a covector.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how that helps, can you drop another hint?

Comment: One needs to use the inverse metric to raise the index on $p_{\mu}$. The metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is non-trivial for spherical coordinates.